# Installing Windows from bootable USB pendrive on UEFI enabled machine

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios, uefi, gpt

I have 5 year old Dell XPS 15. I have installed Windows several time one it using procedure below:

- build bootable USB pendrive from Windows ISO using a [Windows DVD/USB tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool)
- plugging in USB pendrive to my laptop
- booting my laptop from my pendrive
- following on screen steps of Windows (Optionally formatting and partitioning the hard disk if required. However I did not used any explicit tool for that. Formatting and partitioning options used to show up when I boot from USB drive. So its one of the steps in Windows installation )

Now my friend has given me his new laptop **Lenove Y510p** to fix, and it **SEEMS** that it has this UEFI thingy. Earlier I used to do installation (on non-UEFI/BIOS machines) straight as explained above. But reading online about UEFI is confusing me alot. It involves a lot not easily understandable read: GPT, MBR etc...

So I want crisp minimal no confusing steps the way I used to do it ealier. What I have done till now is

- I have downloaded Windows 10 ISO.
- Create bootable USB drive using Rufus (During creating bootable drive, it has `MBR partition scheme for BIOS or UEFI computers` option selected, though I didnt know if that is what I should keep selected, it seems that I must go for  `GPT partition scheme for UEFI computer`)
- I tried booting from pen drive. First realised that this laptop have two power on buttons!!! First on boots windows. Second one shows many power options. On selecting boot options, it has following options:

  - Normal Windows boot
  - IPv4 boot
  - IPv6 boot

  But no boot from USB.
- I tried to go into its BISO menu. Their was option to enable UEFI mode or enable legacy BIOS mode.

I didnt do anything further as I was lacking knowledge about proper procedure and underlying concepts. I felt I will read stuff online and decide...but I find its very difficult to get clear instructions as I stated above. Many tutorials online requires to run some commands and I am very uncomfortable to do so, as I never done so earlier in Windows installation. Earlier all I was used to deal with onscreen options of Windows setup booted from USB drive. I tried going through many articles, references and tutorials like these: [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn938372(v=vs.85).aspx), [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn938340(v=vs.85).aspx), [3](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/186875-uefi-unified-extensible-firmware-interface-install-windows-7-a.html), [4](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/15458-uefi-bootable-usb-flash-drive-create-windows.html), [5](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/), [6](http://www.howtogeek.com/175649/what-you-need-to-know-about-using-uefi-instead-of-the-bios/).

But seems that I am not coming up with any proper steps. Am just trying to form some as follows and need others guidance if I am wrong below. **Q1.** So please guide me if I am missing anything or going wrong in some step.

1. Create bootable USB using Windows 10 ISO and Rufus as shown in figure below:
   [image]

   So I have to select option `GPT partition scheme for UEFI computer` for `Partition scheme` and select `FAT32`
2. Turn off Secure boot (thought I have not yet found option to do so in this laptop, just read online that I have to do so) (Also may be that will show up boot from USB option which is currently not there)
3. Keep UEFI mode (not Legacy BIOS)
4. Boot from USB
5. Follow onscreen options of Windows setup. (I will be mostly doing repartitioning. So if it asks I will be going for GPT for initializing HDD)

**Q2.** If nothing works, can I set `Legacy BIOS` mode and perform old way installation by creating bootable USB drive using rufus with `MBR partition scheme for BIOS` option?

**Q3.** Will installing using UEFI have any impact on Windows activation? Will it auto activate his Windows too?